# Is there a tool to clean up a CSS stylesheet?

Tags: css, parsing

I'm working on a code base where the previous developers made the curious decision to build all the selectors around single properties

For example:

```
.panel .selected a, a.selected-thumb, .date-picker input[type="submit"], .heading-end a, .errormessage .search-box input[type="submit"],
.search-results .search-box input[type="submit"], .article-box-heading.red, .opinion-heading a,
.no-js .tab > a:hover, .touch .tab > a:hover, .tab > .active, 
.box-bottom h5 a, .directory dt a,
.directory dd a:hover, .footer-copy p a
{
  color: #fff;
}
```

The stylesheet is 5000 lines long. I'd like to separate all selectors and compose them into rules with their matching properties.

Does such a thing exist?

Comment: Use css preprocessor and rewrite this code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this website :

[Click here](http://tools.maxcdn.com/procssor/)

Using this website you can separate the selectors easily . Free to use this online .

Comment: All that really did was put each selector on its own line

Comment: did u tried this website mentioned in above answer . if u have css link can u provide i will make it for u ... @spinners